# Qt 5.5 WebEngineView with google map api causes mem leak

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, memory-leaks, qml

I use QML WebEngineView to load an HTML file which contains a google map from google map api v3.25. However, whenever I interact with the map (zoom, pan..), mem leak happens. It works fine when I run the HTML in chrome browser. Has anyone been experiencing this and came up with a solution ?

Comment: Never mind, I switched to Qt 5.7 and this got fixed